# How can I resolve the errors with Xcode version 15.1 - "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods"?

Tags: flutter, xcode, cocoapods

I recently updated MacOS to Ventura 13.6.3 and Xcode to 15.1, and I have been unable to build my Flutter project. I've encountered multiple errors and warnings, and I've been all over Stack Overflow and Apple Developer Forum trying to knock them down, but I just can't get past them.

First, the error in the title of this post:

1. `"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods".`

With much weeping and gnashing of teeth I managed to update Cocoapods to ver 1.14.3, the latest release.

Running pod install, pod deintegrate -> pod update, removing PodFile.lock and the Pods folder and running pod install, removing the derived data folder, cleaning the build folder, quitting and restarting Xcode, restarting the computer...  No combination of these measures that I have tried makes a difference.

There are many posts about this error, and I've looked at most of them, and tried what they said.

In Targets -> Runner -> Build Phases -> [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock I changed the setting for Run Script to "For install builds only" and delete input and output files and file lists. This causes the following errors to appear:

- `GeneratedPluginRegistrant 'Flutter/Flutter.h' files not found`
- `<ProjectPath>/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h:1:9 failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fdmlwujdkwtasydspyforcabevwa/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_J5ABRLVSYS1U-clang_1MXK62JDBC6KG.pch' for bridging header '<ProjectPath>/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'`

  Running pod install again replaces the input and output files in this setting but brings me to the next error:

2. `Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist'` and same for `...-output-files.xcfilelist`.

   In Targets -> Runner -> Build Phases [CP] Embed Pods Frameworks I delete values from Input File Lists and Output File Lists, and this allows the build to get past this phase, but then another build replaces these files and generates error #1.
3. When I do a `pod install` I get these warnings:

```
   [!] The `Runner [Debug]` target overrides the `PODS_BUILD_DIR` build setting
     defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig'. 
     This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
       - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
       - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

This warning appears for several env variables similar to `PODS_BUILD_DIR` for the debug, profile and release targets. I have put the `$(inherited)` flag in all these properties, but these warnings persist. Xcode does not allow me to remove those build settings.

I don't know if all these issues are related to the update or if anyone else is seeing them. I also don't know if these arise from the same underlying issue or if they are separate issues. Any help will be greatly appreciated.